# Проблема с получением ответа с сервера

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

Добрый день!

Формирую файл pdf на сервере и возвращаю его на клиент для последующего сохранения в браузере. Сформированный файл весит ~370 КБ, но на клиент передается лишь 255,8 КБ, остальная часть обрезается. Файлы меньшего размера передаются без ошибок.

В логах наблюдается следующее:

```
epoll_ctl(): File exists [core/event.c line 651]
OSError: write error
epoll_ctl(): No such file or directory [core/event.c line 635]
```

Используется python 3.4 + nginx + uwsgi.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как вы отдаете файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена путем добавления в nginx.conf параметра *uwsgi_buffers*:

```
uwsgi_buffers 8 512k;
```